# Strange behaviour for String.replaceAll() with number string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

```
String pre = "895";
System.out.println(pre);
pre = pre.replaceAll(".", "");
System.out.println(pre);
```

The output strangely is:

```
895
```

So all numbers are erased from the string. Why is this?

Comment: replaceAll takes regex as first parameter, so '.' is any character

Comment: What do you think should happen instead? Which part of *documentation* of `replaceAll` makes you think so?

Comment: What did you expect it to output?

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given **regular expression** with the given replacement. Simply use `pre.replace(".", "")` if you don't want to use regex

Comment: ReplaceAll() is unappropriate in this case because it is a regEx.

Comment: It is time for you to **learn regex**, and one of the very first thing any regex tutorial will teach you, is that `.` period is a meta-character matching anything (except line separators). To fix, escape the character, which needs double-escaping in a Java string literal, i.e. `replaceAll("\\.", "")`, or ask the system to do it, i.e. `replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."), "")`, or don't use regex version, i.e. `replace(".", "")`.

Comment: Did you read the _javadoc_ for method `replaceAll()`? If you did then did you understand it? Your question, in my opinion, is a RTFM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that the `replaceAll` method uses `REGEX` as first parameter.
In REGEX `.` means any character so currently you are replacing any character with `""`.
Thats the reason why your result is empty.
If you want to replace with a specific character you should use `pre.replace(".", "");`.